# fstab issue mount system call failed not a directory

Tags: mount, fstab, ssd

I added two extra entries in my fstab file in an attempt to move tmp directories off SSD to HDD:

```
/dev/sdb1 /tmp none bind 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /var/tmp none bind 0 0
```

However this stops my PC from booting up and there's an error: "mount: /var/tmp: mount(2) system call failed: Not a directory"

What am I doing wrong? How can I move those temp dirs from my SSD to HDD?

Comment: Why are you attempting to mount that partition into two different directories? If you want its contents to be on the HDD, then just create a directory on the HDD and change `/etc/fstab` to mount it there.

Comment: If you only intend to just move files from one disk to another, there is no need to add an entry to `/etc/fstab`. The file `/etc/fstab` holds items to be mounted by the system on **every** boot with `mount -a`. Instead, you should just temporarily mount the two disks with mount commands, `mount /dev/sdXn /some_dir; mount /dev/sdYm /other_dir` and then rsync(1) or cp(1) files from `/some_dir` to `/other_dir`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to the `/dev/sdb1` device (fstab field #1), not the `/tmp` directory (field #2).

You have specifed the `bind` mount option (fstab field #4) and in this case is the syntax of the mount call:

```
mount -o bind olddir newdir
```

and not the usual `mount device mountdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message says that `/var/tmp` is not a directory. As you seem to have access to the filesystem, you should do an `ls -l /var` to see if `/var/tmp` exists and if it does, it is a directory. It depends a bit on your system, but it might be that `/var/tmp` is a link to `/tmp`.

Comment: i can confirm that both /var/tmp and /tmp are directories

Comment: Yet, `mount` does not see it. Is `/var` on a separate partition, that may not yet have been mounted when you mount `/var/tmp`?

Comment: /var is on the same partition as /tmp (some /dev/sdaX)

Comment: Can you add the full `fstab` to your question?